# MySQL Stored Procedure: Works manually & not with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working with stored procedures for the first time. I'm facing hard time figuring out problem behind this.
If I execute stored procedure from **PhpMyAdmin** manually, it works fine. But when I use it with C# program. It shows error.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Save`(INOUT `id` INT, IN `cId` INT, IN `date` DATE, IN `randomNum` INT, IN `debitAmount` VARCHAR(20), IN `descr` VARCHAR(255))
NO SQL

BEGIN
INSERT INTO dc (status, dcDate, clientId) VALUES ('1', date, cId);
SET id = last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO bill (dcId, clientId, billDate, referenceNo) VALUES (
    id,
    clientId,
    date,
    randomNum
);

INSERT INTO ledger (clientId, debit, ledgerDate, description, dcId, referenceNo) 
VALUES (
    cId,
    debitAmount,
    date,
    descr,
    id,
    randomNum
);


SELECT @id;

END
```

When I execute this procedure with these parameters:

```
var reader = connection.StoredProcedureInOut("Save", new String[] { "0", theDate, clientId, randomNumber.ToString(), totalDebit.ToString(), description }, new String[] { "id", "date", "cId","randomNum", "debitAmount", "descr" });
```

Definition is:

```
 public MySqlDataReader StoredProcedureInOut(String procedureName, String[] values, String[] keys)
    {
        openConnection();
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + keys[i], values[i]);

            }
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            reader = null;
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

I get this message:

```
OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine noorani.Save is not a variable or NEW pseduo-variable in Before trigger
```

Comment: Try to set first parameter as output parameter. Take a look at this answer for example [Retrieving SQL Server output variables in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389192/retrieving-sql-server-output-variables-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem by altering the code like this:

```
var reader = connection.StoredProcedureInOut("Save", new String[] {theDate, clientId, randomNumber.ToString(), totalDebit.ToString(), description }, new String[] {"date", "cId","randomNum", "debitAmount", "descr" }, new String[] {"id"});
```

Definition:

```
public String[] StoredProcedureInOut(String procedureName, String[] values, String[] keys, String[] outputParameters)
    {
        openConnection();
        String[] newlyInsertedID = new String[outputParameters.Length];
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(procedureName, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            for (int i = 0; i < outputParameters.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + outputParameters[i], "0");
                var parameterName = "@"+outputParameters[i];
                cmd.Parameters[parameterName].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + keys[i], values[i]);
                var parameterName = "@" + keys[i];
                cmd.Parameters[parameterName].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            }
            //reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            for(int i = 0; i < outputParameters.Length; i++)
            {
                var parameterName = "@"+outputParameters[i];

                newlyInsertedID[i] = cmd.Parameters[parameterName].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            //reader = null;
        }
        closeConnection();
        return newlyInsertedID;
    }
```

Thing which was missing in the code was **Direction**. Moreover this is a generic code can be executed for all types of Out/InOut stored Procedures.

Hope this is helpful.